# Mapping also for one element (or telling it how to do so if head got changed)

Tags: function-construction, functional-style, map

Some code generates a polynomial, and has the form:

```
expr = Plus[a[i],b[i],c[i],d[i]]
```

I need to apply `f` to each term.  To do this, I use `Map`:

```
Map[f, expr]

(* f[a[i]] + f[b[i]] + f[c[i]] + f[d[i]]  *)
```

But sometimes, my code generates polynomial with one term, and has the following form.

```
expr = Plus[a[i]]
(* this is actually just a[i] *)
```

Then when it goes to `Map`:

```
Map[f, expr]
(* a[f[i]] *)
```

The `f` got confused because the head `Plus` disappeared.  So what can do to make `f` apply to a one-element thing (without using `If` and `Then` statements which I believe is slow)?

Comment: That's what lists are for!

Comment: Got it.  Thanks!

Comment: @belisarius I posted an answer based on your comment.  Would you suggest which is better (meaning *faster*)?  `Plus @@ ` or `Total @ `?

Comment: Try `k = RandomReal[1, 1000000];Timing[Plus @@ k;][[1]] > Timing[Total@k;][[1]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that `List` has the special property that the head doesn't disappear even with one element.  So the solution (as belisarius noted in the comment) is to make the code generate `expr` with `Head`=`List` instead of `Plus` *i.e*,

```
expr = List[a[i],b[i],c[i],d[i]]
```

Then I can safely pass this to `Map` as in `Map[f, expr]`, and it doesn't matter how many elements `f` has.  Now I just need to replace the `List` with `Plus`.

```
Plus @@ Map[f, expr]
```

Comment: As an alternative, you could generate the code with head Inactive[Plus], then map your function f and use Activate.

Comment: @FredSimons Yes, that is a good alternative